# Best data type to use to map JSON arrays to DTOs in C# / ASP .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, model, dto

This is probably a dumb question, but I was wondering the following:
I have a .Net 5 Web API, and in it I want to create a DTO to accept a POST request from a front end.
The body in the POST request contains the following JSON:

```
{
    "aComment": "This is a text field",
    "aNumber": 5,
    "anArray": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

In the controller, I have an action method that will receive this request and map it into a DTO ("SomeDto"):

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<SomeDto>> Post()
{
    // Some code
}
```

What would be the best data type to use in DTO for that JSON integer array?

```
* int[]

* ICollection<int>

* IEnumerable<int>

* List<int>
```

I'm leaning towards ICollection or IEnumerable becuase they are lighter than List. But I suppose int[] could also work nicely?

**EDIT:**

I see that .Net Core, when scaffolding an existing database, creates collections of type ICollection, and initializes them in the class constructor. Example:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public SomeModel()
    {
        Accounts = new HashSet<Account>();
    }

    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

So maybe I should also use ICollection? Although in the scaffolded example above, the collection is of type "Account" (i.e. an object). Not sure if that would also be a good fit a simple collection of a primitive type such as Integer?

Comment: Thanks Sami. Not sure if I understood you correctly, but the JSON array ("anArray") can have varying number of elements, but the elements are always of primitive type integer. Your suggestion is to use int[] then, is that right?

Comment: Just use what fits well - there is no "The best" data type. If your collection never changes - use array, if changes from time to time, but does not preserve order - use `ICollection<T>`, if it is ordered collection - use `IList<T>`.

Comment: I would just prefer not to use `IEnumerable<int>` because I refer it to data that might not be materialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dynamic` here

public async Task<ActionResult<**dynamic**>> Post()

Comment: question was about how to design `SomeDto`, not how to throw it out of controller